# Java variable values persist in memory after responding to a request

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

I'm going to deploy a Java application using [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/getting-started-async/src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm) docker image. I'm trying to eliminate the issue that the variable's value persists even after the response is generated. My assumption is to have an isolated environment per each request, BUT I'm not sure is correct or not.

For example, the given code block below will add the given URL param to a dummy list.

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    private final List<String> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response hello(@PathParam("param") String param) throws InterruptedException {
        dummyList.add(param);
        
        return Response.ok(dummyList.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

If you curl the endpoint twice like:

```
/hello/client1
/hello/client2
```

my expectation is to receive:

```
[client1]
[client2]
```

but what I get actually is:

```
[client1]
[client1, client2]
```

This will make me a little worried about the concurrent sessions, and the question is how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why:

```
private final List<String> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();
```

As a rule of thumb: [**Never** keep instance variables](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/java-concurrency-troubleshooting-data-access-and-consistency/unsafe-class-level-variable-access) in service classes. Use DTOs and value objects to maintain state wherever you can. What you have up there is a big no-no in building service oriented architectures.

For this scenario specifically, Quarkus defaults the scope of the service class ( `GreetingResources`) to singleton scope, which means a single instance will be used to serve all requests.

You can change this behaviour by configuring the [`quarkus.resteasy.singleton-resources`](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-resteasy-server-common_quarkus.resteasy.singleton-resources) property in your config.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a clean response after every method call, you can try declaring the arraylist inside the method.

```
@GET
@Path("/{param}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response hello(@PathParam("param") String param) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();
    dummyList.add(param);
    
    return Response.ok(dummyList.toString()).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one instance of the GreetingResource class (singleton) servering all your requests. They will share the instance variables you defines in your class like f.x. `dummyList`.

If you need stuff with scope request you can inject a bean with scope request like f.x.

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public HelloMessageGenerator requestScopedBean() {
    return new HelloMessageGenerator();
}
```

This example is from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes.

You might want to move `dummyList` inside your `hello` method if that will work for you.

If this not solve your issue it would be helpfull if you could give us some info about why you need this `dummyList` variable.